# redirect domain in azure

Tags: azure, redirect

`mydomain.pk` is live.
i want `anotherdomain.pk` to be redirected to `mydomain.pk`

**Details:**

1. `abc` is my domain registrar
2. `godaddy` is my hosting provider
3. Then I decided to use hosting from azure
4. In godaddy DNS settings i added a cname Host=`awverify` points to=`awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net` to bring external domain under azure.
5. External domain i.e, `mydomain.pk` brought successfully. Everything working fine
6. Then i bought `anotherdomain.pk` from `def` domain registrar.
7. Want to redirect `anotherdomain.pk` to `mydomain.pk`
8. Change nameservers to one provided by Godaddy. `mydomain.pk` also use these nameservers.
9. Added cname under `mydomain.pk` DNS Manager but not working.
10. Cannot find any settings in azure portal.

How can I redirect ?

Comment: In the DNZ zone file for `anotherdomain.pk`, make exact same settings you did for `mydomain.pk`. That should do the trick.

Comment: i don't have DNS zone file for `anotherdomain.pk`. I haven't hosted this domain. (My current hosting plan at godaddy allows only one domain).

Comment: `mydomain.pk` is verified by azure. Can I remove it from godaddy hosting? and use `anotherdomain.pk` instead?

Comment: So if I understand correctly (and also based on our conversation in your previous question :)), you have pointed your website (mydomain.pk) to Azure, so essentially it is hosted in Azure  and not GoDaddy. Am I correct?

Comment: yes. i'm glad to having a conversion with you again!

Comment: @GauravMantri i'm waiting for your kind reply